# Server IP address showing in Google search results instead of domain

Tags: wordpress, server, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

My WordPress website is hosted on Google Cloud Platform running Unix on Apache+Varnish (Bitnami Image). I have wp-rocket plugin installed and my dns is being managed by Cloudflare.

The domain and server IP both are showing in search results.

What could causing server to show ip address in Google search results instead of domain?

Comment: Please add details what exactly is happening, what you've tried to fix it and any context that seems useful.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: My Server Ip Address is Showing in Google Search results instead of Domain. I didn't find any solution on Web thus haven't tried anything to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your domain pointing to the server you are hosting the WP instance on.

DNS records should have an A record pointing to the server IP.

Also, depending on whether you pointed your domain to the WP instance sometime after creation, you just need to wait for Google to crawl your site again.

If you set up a Google Webmasters account (now called Google Search Console), you can force a new crawl.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

Comment: My DNS is being managed by Cloudflare. And when I add CNAME POINTING TO MY IP IT'S Giving me Error. "CNAME CANNOT CONTAIN AN IP". One more thing how do I force Google to crawl again?

Comment: Edited answer should be an A Record not Cname. Added link to answer for crawl.

Comment: A name is already there which is pointing to my ip. I added it a while ago

Comment: Without more info I am not sure how to help you. Maybe screen shots with ip address covered over. Maybe try an easier implementation of hosting Wordpress.  Godaddy, Digital Ocean.. other hosting sites like this all offer "Managed Wordpress" solutions. This gives you less control of the server and environment but can get you up and running quickly.  To migrate your current site to a new wp instance I recommend using the [All-in-one Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) wordpress plugin.

Comment: @noes1s hi. I know it's too late, but were you able to solve this problem, having a similar one now.

Comment: @SunilLulla - Have you checked if your wp-config.php contains URLs instead of IPs? it should look like this:  
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com');
Another place to check is the sitemap, again, it should have domain name, not IP.